# How to assert new rule from user input (PROLOG)

Tags: input, prolog, rule, fact, prolog-assert

I want to accept users' input, i.e. `[garfield, hates, blacky]`.
`hates/2` doesn't exist currently.

In my database,

```
process:-
    read(Input_List),
    add_rule(Input_List).

add_rule([X, Predicate, Y]):-
    assertz(Predicate(X, Y)).
```

But this doesn't work. Is it possible to use a variable as predicate, and facts?
Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `(=..)/2` operator called [univ operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2) :

```
add_rule(X, Predicate, Y) :-
    Fact =.. [Predicate, X, Y],
    assertz(Fact).
```

Usage :

```
?- add_rule(garfield, hates, blacky).
true.

?- hates(garfield, blacky).
true.
```